# How to upgrade hibernate-jpamodelgen from 5 to 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metamodel

I have a working project with this maven section:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <processors>
                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
            </processors>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jpametamodel</outputDirectory>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpamodelgen.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When `hibernate-jpamodelgen.version`=`5.6.14.Final`, it works.

When I try to upgrade to `6.1.6.Final`, the classes are not generated, hence I get compilation errors.

Comment: You should probably switch to [org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.1.6.Final](https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen/6.1.6.Final) (note: the groupId changed). Otherwise, you'll need to be a bit more explicit in your problem description (e.g. provide a [mre] and include all errors). Also be aware that Hibernate 6 is one big breaking change given it changed to the `jakarta.persistence.*` package namespace (JPA 3), where Hibernate 5.6 used the `javax.persistence` package namespace (JPA 2.2).

Comment: That is not required to use `maven-processor-plugin`, adding `hibernate-jpamodelgen` to the project dependencies with `scope=provided` should be enough.